# Snowflake insert into a table from CTE output results

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

```
with 
ct2 (emp_name,emp_id) as (
  select emp_name,emp_id  
  from "TEST_1"."PUBLIC"."TEST11"
)
insert into "TEST_1"."PUBLIC"."EMP1"  
select emp_name,emp_id 
from ct2;
```

Comment: Your question is missing.

Comment: I was in a rush so I forgot to explain the problem but you got me right.  :) 
thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you are looking for the correct syntax to achieve the above.

Try this:

```
insert into "TEST_1"."PUBLIC"."EMP1"
with ct2 (emp_name,emp_id) as (select emp_name,emp_id from "TEST_1"."PUBLIC"."TEST11")
select emp_name,emp_id from ct2;
```

Comment: its working, appreciate your help.. Thanks a lot